# How to reset all dynamically created multiselects (PrimeNG) in Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

In my code I create dynamically `p-multiselects` like below:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filterConfig;>
  <div *ngIf="filter.type === 'dropdown'" class="filterSession">
    <app-dropdown-menu [config]="filter"></app-dropdown-menu>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and in my dropdown component I create the multiselect:

**Component**

```
multiselectOptions = new FormControl();

resetDropdowns() {
 // console.log(this.multiselectOptions);
 this.multiselectOptions.reset();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="data" defaultLabel="Select options" optionLabel="valueName" 
  dataKey="valueId" [showHeader]="false" [formControl]="multiselectOptions" (onChange)="onSearch()">
</p-multiSelect>
```

As a legit result it only resets the first multiselect cause all the `formcontrols` have the same name and it cannot "recognize" what I want to reset.
I am thinking that I need to create in my dropdown component an array of `FormControl()` and then add it in every dropdown that is being created.

Any idea of how to do this?

P.S. The reset function is called by another sibling component.

Comment: Have a look at [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

Comment: @Antikhippe that's what I am looking at right now!